# Bin Packing Objective function

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem, packing, objective-function

First I want to clarify that English is not my native language so have me a little patience :)

I'm trying to solve the  3D bin packing problem, only with one container(knapsack) and I have a problem about the formulation of the objective function. I have a container and a list of packages:

Container:

- Width
- Depth
- Height
- Capacity
- Three dimensional matrix

Package:

- Width
- Depth
- Height
- Position (X,Y,Z)
- Weight
- Position Factor

Each package will have a position factor, which tells us in what position you want to load the package, factor ranging from 1 to 5, 1 means that the package should be placed in the front of the container and a 5 in the back of the container.

Now my objective function is to maximize the space on the container and the packages that have a greater factor have to be in the back of the container and the packages with lower factor in the front of the truck.

If i want to maximize the space, i just have to maximize the sum of all the package volumnes, but  i should combine this with a penalty to the objective function when, for example, a package with a factor of 5 is in position the front of the container.

I want to clarify something with an example packages of equal size arranged in a line

1. back 5 1 5 4 4 4 3 3 2 2 front
2. back 5 5 4 4 4 3 3 2 1 2 front

In the first distribution packet,you see that  the package of a factor of 1 is almost at the back of the container, while in the second distribution the package with a factor of 1 is located near the position where
should be (front), so the second distribution is better.

The problem is that packets have different sizes and can be placed in any position. I hope you can help me :D!

Answer (score 0):

A particular form of objective function depends on solving method.

As bin packing problem is NP-hard problem I guess that you'll use some heuristics to solve it. In this case candidate solution is set of all packages (P) with filled Position (X,Y,Z) attribute. And objective function looks like:

```
F({P}) -> int
```

So you can add weight its result by package factor: the best layout is sorted factors from 1 to 5 as I understand. Difference between it and current layout is your coefficient (use least squares):

```
ideal:   back 5 5 4 4 4 3 3 2 2 1 front
current: back 5 1 5 4 4 4 3 3 2 2 front 
coefficient: (5-5)^2 + (5-1)^2 + ... + (1-2)^2
```